# How to Export from PHP to Excel (xlsx)

Tags: php, sql-server, excel

I am trying to export to an xlsx file from a MSSQL query in PHP. I don't have access to the servers that my website is hosted on so i can't use anything that isn't already built into PHP. I'm using PHP 5.4. So far I've created a `<a></a>` that references a php page that should pull data from my MSSQL DB. Instead it gives me a blank file, in xls format. When I open it it throws an error about not having a stylesheet.css file in the downloads folder then opens a blank xls workbook. Here's my ExportToExcel.php file:

```
$tsql = "select ID, TableName, UpdateDate from pmdb.TableUpdates order by UpdateDate";
//echo $tsql . "<br>";
$getqueries = $conn->query($tsql);
//echo "<BR>";
//var_dump($getqueries);
$result = $getqueries->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
$filename = "TableUpdates";
//var_dump($tsql);

header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");

/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/

//define separators (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
$br = "\r\n"; //line break

//start of printing column names as names of SQL fields
//$max = sqlsrv_num_fields($result);
/* for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
echo sqlsrv_field_metadata($result,$i) . "\t";
}
print("\n"); */

foreach( sqlsrv_field_metadata( $result ) as $fieldMetadata ) {
foreach( $fieldMetadata as $name => $value) {
   echo "$value" . $sep;
}
}   
echo $br;

//end of printing column names

//start while loop to get data
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch($result))
{
    $schema_insert = "";
    for($j=0; $j<sqlsrv_num_fields($result);$j++)
    {
        if(!isset($row[$j]))
            $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
        elseif ($row[$j] != "")
            $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
        else
            $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
    }
    $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert .= "\t";
    print(trim($schema_insert));
    print "\n";
}
```

I got most of this from other questions, but none of them had an answer either.

**EDIT**

I have gotten a little further. I can now print the data to excel, though it still throws the errors

> The file format and extension of . . . don't match . . .

and

> Problems During Load: Missing file: C:\Users\username\Downloads\StyleSheet.css

,but everything prints in one column. It is comma separated, but all values are in the same column. Here's the new portion of the code:

```
//define separators (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
$sep = ","; //tabbed character
$br = "<br>"; //line break

$hsql = "select Headings from TableHeadings where TableName = 'TableUpdates' order by ID";
$getHeadings = $conn->query($hsql);
$rHeadings = $getHeadings->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$headings = array($rHeadings[0]["Headings"],$rHeadings[1]["Headings"],$rHeadings[2]["Headings"]);

//start of printing column names as names of SQL fields
foreach($headings as $Heading => $value)
{
    echo "$value" . $sep;
}
echo $br;
for ($i = 0;$i < 3;$i++)
{
    for($l = 0;$l < 3;$l++)
    {
        if ($l == 0)
        {
            echo $result[$i]["ID"] . $sep;
        }
        elseif ($l == 1)
        {
            echo $result[$i]["TableName"] . $sep;
        }
        else
        {
            echo $result[$i]["UpdateDate"];
        }
    }
    echo $br;
}
```

How can I get this to echo each value and then move to the next cell? It does have commas, but looks like this:

```
ID,TableName,UpdateDate,
1,pmdb.MaterialTracking,2016-07-08 13:45:05.963
2,pmdb.OSP_OPR_Report,2016-07-08 13:45:45.883
3,pmdb.COEI_OPR_Report,2016-07-08 13:45:47.920
```

Comment: You're not creating an xls file. `.xls` is a compound-ole format. You're generating a .csv file and LYING to excel what its type is.  That's why Excel is telling you the format doesn't match. There is NOTHING you can do to bypass this, because Excel knows you're lying to it. Either use a proper excel library, or tell Excel it's a csv file, the proper way.

Comment: @MarcB I thought that this was the proper library `header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")`. If not then what is or how do I change it to a csv? If I new I'd have done it already.

Comment: that's not a library. that's just telling the client "I'm sending you a file of this type". and then you send data that's a completely different type

Comment: @MarcB I did not know that. I thought that was the library. Where do I specify the library then? And what should I change the header to so that it'll see that I'm sending a csv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the `header` so that Excel knows that it's a csv file that it's opening. I no longer get either error.

```
header("Content-Type: application/x-csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.csv");
```

I still don't have any other libraries, so there is not going to be any formatting, just a csv file.